# How can I remove web phone links from opening in Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-chrome, facetime

For whatever reason, Google Hangouts has taken over as my dialer whenever I click on a phone number on the web (either Chrome or Safari). I want to restore this to open in FaceTime, but no longer have that option. In the FaceTime settings, FaceTime is still listed as the default dialer.

Any idea where Chrome would have made this change and how I can revert it? Better yet, how can i remove all remnants of google hangouts from my life??

Comment: Which platform are you using?   iPhone?   Mac?    Also, you mentioned removing it all together...  did you uninstall, but you are still seeing changed functionality even after uninstalling hangouts?   How did you uninstall?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about removing hangouts completely (perhaps use a cleaning tool such as CleanMyMac, though many users dislike that type of app), but I have a suggesting for changing how telephone links are handled: try [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), a free prefpane which manages default apps for opening different types of files and URIs.

Using that prefpane, you could change the default setting for `tel` URLs to open using the FaceTime app.

More details on modifying the files that control these defaults are in this answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/548122/190749).

Comment: RCDefaultApp no longer works since MacOS 10.12 due to deprecation of ObjC Garbage collection.  Try SwiftDefaultApps at https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps on Github

Answer (score 1):

I am using SwiftDefaultApps in macOS Mojave, to manage URL and application handlers. "tel" is set to FaceTime and yet clicking on telephone number links, in Chrome, is still opening Hangouts.